# Set period between lowercase letter followed by uppercase letter in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

Is there a way to use `str.replaceAll()` function with regular expression to set a period and space `(". ")` between each lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter? Or is there another way to achieve the following transformation?

e.g. `"First sentenceSecond sentenceLast sentence"` to `"First sentence. Second sentence. Last sentence"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use replaceAll with this regex [**`([a-z])([A-Z])`**](https://regex101.com/r/v8xfki/1) which will match two groups the first one is the lowercase letter the second the uppercase letter, then replace them with `$1. $2` like so :

```
String str = "First sentenceSecond sentenceLast sentence";

str = str.replaceAll("([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1. $2");
```

Output

```
First sentence. Second sentence. Last sentence
```

Comment: Wow, simple and smart!

Comment: Thank you @shahaf yes regex is really nice :)

Comment: @YCF_L nice answer. Can you explain little what is significant of `$1. $2`. Thanks

Comment: @AmitBera `$1` will match the first group which is `([a-z])` lowercase character, and `$2` will match the second group `([A-Z])` which is uppercase character so replace this two groups with a dot and a space between them this is what does mean hope you got it

Comment: @YCF_L Ok, now I got it. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect, thank you @YCF_L, excellent answer and nice explanation! Works perfectly!