# Split camel case string with number special treatment

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to split camel case string with special treatment for numbers (in Java). I tried some regex but without success. Examples below:

```
SomeString -> ["Some", "String"]
SomeString1 -> ["Some", "String1"]
SomeString1Word -> ["Some", "String1Word"]
```

Any ideas what regex i should use?

Edit: Rule: Split by camel cases but not split when number is between small and big letter. Don't split also when number is last character. This will fit my requirements.

Comment: What is the general splitting rule here? You didn't state it.

Comment: Is the string always alphanumeric?

Comment: so only split on `[lower][upper]` pattern? i think this post may direct you in the right way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890664/set-period-between-lowercase-letter-followed-by-uppercase-letter-in-java/50890697

Comment: @user1055395 yes, strings are always alphanumeric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to split *before* any uppercase letter that is preceded by a lowercase letter, i.e. *between* a lowercase letter and an uppercase letter, so:

Split using regular expression:         `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`
Or using POSIX character class:     `(?<=\p{Lower})(?=\p{Upper})`
Or using java.lang.Character class: `(?<=\p{javaLowerCase})(?=\p{javaUpperCase})`
Or using Unicode Category class:   `(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})`

`(?<=X)` is a zero-width positive lookbehind.
`(?=X)` is a zero-width positive lookahead.

*Demo*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("SomeString");
    test("SomeString1");
    test("SomeString1Word");
}
private static void test(String text) {
    String regex = "(?<=\\p{Ll})(?=\\p{Lu})";
    System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", text, Arrays.toString(text.split(regex)));
}
```

*Output*

```
SomeString -> [Some, String]
SomeString1 -> [Some, String1]
SomeString1Word -> [Some, String1Word]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.split("(?<![0-9])(?=[A-Z])")
```

Answer (score 1):

By luck, I think I managed to have found the pattern you're looking for:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

Tests:

```
"SomeString".split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])")      // [Some, String]
"SomeString1".split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])")     // [Some, String1]
"SomeString1Word".split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])") // [Some, String1Word]
```